# Is Explicit Versioning a better alternative to Semantic Versioning for wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization, cms, version-control

Semantic Version has 3 digits for versioning of the code (1.0.0.), is Explicit Versioning with 4 digits (1.0.0.0.) and not 100% API focus a better approach for Wordpress or Drupal developers?

https://github.com/colomet/Explicit-Versioning

Comment: what!?!?!!?!?!?!?

Comment: Please don't cross post ... Just saw this at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347960/is-cms-versioning-with-4-componentts-in-version-numbers-a-good-alternative-to

Answer (score -1):

Semantic versioning is better for WordPress.

I used 4 digits in one of my plugin versions once and it didn't play nice.

[Here's a page from Make WordPress Core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/about/release-cycle/version-numbering/)

Comment: sorry but this is not really an answer. why is it better?, what is it better in?

Comment: It is better to use semantic versioning for WordPress plugins so the version numbers are consistent with updates, alerting the user that there is a new update at the correct time. It's also in line with WordPress core... So that's why it would be better to use it in WordPress plugins. OP asked for best approach to WordPress development. I can't answer for Drupal, but it certainly applies to WordPress @MarkKaplun

Comment: users rarely know what version they have installed.... either they get the upgrade notification or they don't upgrade. In one of my plugins I went from a 4.1 version to 4.6 and literally no one asked about it.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But isn't it fair to say for WordPress that semantic versioning is recommended for development in WordPress plugins since core uses it themselves? If not for anything else but consistency?

Comment: @BenbodhiMantra wordpress core do not use semantic versioning. WP increase the Minor from 1 to 0 and then change the Major in phases of development time, not if there is a breack or a feature..

Comment: For me the main issue with versioning is how easily can a user detect he is running an old/out of date code. I have decided to sync my release dates to wordpress releases, and just name them by the wp release name. Other options are to use actual dates (ubuntu does it, microsoft does it with many products). if your software is constantly updated like chrome/firefox/skype the release version is important only for support. And the point of this comment is that "who are your users" and "what do you want to communicate in the version number" are important, and there is no "one size fits all"

Comment: Sorry, I realise that WordPress isn't quite semantic versioning.